# Fixing Redundancy of Data in Power BI

Tags: database, powerbi, business-intelligence, star-schema

Currently I'm working with a dashboard in which I'm pulling data (this data comes from 2 tables or dimensions) from a star schema, I'm displaying the data in a table component, and this data is not being displayed correctly because it looks like there is redundancy due to the column status(This column originally calls name and it is in the pracHeaderStatus table). Here I'm adding some screenshots:

**Relationships:**

[image]

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

(The ID's repeat many times)

Note: 
I do not get this problem with querying my data from sql server

Greetings!

Comment: What status values do you expect to see?

Comment: @AlexisOlson Well, We can just have one status per project title

Comment: `pracHeader` has a `StatusID` as well. Does this match up with `pracDetails.StatusID` and hece `pracHeaderStatus.ID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked with the people that made this database and apparently this data was being retrieved from a transactional database while power BI was interpreting it as a star schema, so in other words. The problem is that the relationships are wrong because apparently Power BI always tries to denormalize the data, thinking that is a star or snowflake schema.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the arrows in the diagram. Notice that the `Project Title` is unable to filter the status `Name`. In order for the relationship to work as you expect, there has to be a path between the tables that doesn't go "uphill" (opposite direction of the arrows).

You should be able to fix this by changing the relationship between `pracDetails` and `pracHeaderStatus`to filter both directions. Double click on the relationship line to edit.

[image: Filter both ways]

Comment: hmm, I just changed it to both, but the problem remains, do you know why would it be?

Comment: What tables do `PRAC_Number`, `Status`, and `GoLive` come from?

Comment: sorry my bad i didn't explained that part, so I changed the name of the fields just for displaying reasons(I did not changed it from the data base, so it still has its original name) PRAC_Number = pracHeader.ID,  Status =pracHeaderStatus.NAME, GoLive = this field is in the table pracHeader, just that i did not show it because of the space.